# groupdict in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-re

I have the following string:

```
string = "Malcolm Reynolds"
```

I wrote a regex for this which will find the first-name and last-name of user:

```
m = re.match(r"(?P<first_name>\w+) (?P<last_name>\w+)", "Malcolm Reynolds")
m.groupdict()
```

Result:

```
{'first_name': 'Malcolm', 'last_name': 'Reynolds'}
```

Sometimes, I don't get the last name. At that time, my regex fails. Can any one have any idea regarding this?

Comment: Can you please add the examples where you're not getting the desired result?The regex is fine provided the examples you're testing suits it.

Comment: @Mandy8055 string = "Malcolm" or string = "Reynolds"
In this case my regex is failed.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/XcPHGa/1) help? You can add `?` quantifier in front of  space and lastname.

Comment: Yes. It is working. But if string is "Mr Malcolm Reynolds". Then this regex again fail. Can we add regex for Citations like Mr, Mrs, Miss etc?

Comment: Sometime middle name it is present. But "Mr. Malcolm Reynolds" - This string is confirm. Sometimes citation is not present.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/XcPHGa/3) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:(?:M(?:(?:is|r)?s|r)|[JS]r)\.?\s+)?(?P<first_name>\w+)(?:\s+(?P<last_name>\w+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/avy8RP/4)

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:M(?:(?:is|r)?s|r)|[JS]r)\.?\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching an optional char sequence: `Mr`, `Ms`, `Mrs`, `Miss`, `Jr` or `Sr` with an optional `.` after and 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<first_name>\w+)`  - Group "first_name": one or more word chars
- `(?:\s+(?P<last_name>\w+))?` -  - an optional non-capturing group matching 1+ whitespaces and then capturing into Group "last_name" 1 or more word chars
- `$`  - end of string.